# C - Inserting numbers into an array and maintaining the sorted order

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to create a program that is able to insert integers into an array and maintain its sorted order. i.e. every time you insert a number, it loops through the array to find where it should be inserted, pushes each element after that spot over one index to make room for the insertion, then inserts the value. I can't seem to get this problem solved for whatever reason. If anyone could offer any insight or help, it would much appreciated.

```
struct data
{
    int numbers[10];
    int length;
};

void insert(struct data *x, int newNumber);


void insert(struct data *x, int newNumber)
{
    int i, k;

    if(x->length == 0)
    {
        x->length++;
        x->numbers[0] = newNumber;
    }

    // Increase Length
    x->length = x->length + 1;

    // Loop Through the array
    for(i = 0; i < x->length; i++)
    {
        // Find location where newNumber should come after
        if(x->numbers[i] < newNumber)
        {
            // Shift each element until i
            for(k = x->length-1; k > i; k--)
            {   
                x->numbers[k+1] = x->numbers[k];
            }

            // Set next element equal to newNumber
            x->numbers[k] = newNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

fix like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_ELEMENT_LENGTH 10

struct data {
    int numbers[MAX_ELEMENT_LENGTH];
    int length;
};

void insert(struct data *x, int newNumber){
    int i, k;

    if(x->length == 0){
        x->numbers[x->length++] = newNumber;
    } else if(x->length < MAX_ELEMENT_LENGTH){//need this check
        //x->length = x->length + 1;//Do not increment before the loop. because x->numbers[i] occurs out of bounds

        for(i = 0; i < x->length; i++){   //descending order
            if(x->numbers[i] < newNumber){//descending order
                //insert position is i
                for(k = x->length-1; k >= i; k--){//k > i --> k >= i
                    x->numbers[k+1] = x->numbers[k];
                }
                break;//exit loop
            }
        }
        x->numbers[i] = newNumber;
        x->length++;
    }
}

int main(void){
    //DEMO
    struct data x = { {0}, 0 };

    insert(&x, 5);
    for(int i = 1; i < 11; ++i)
        insert(&x, i);

    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; ++i)
        printf("%d ", x.numbers[i]);
    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That makes much more sense now. I had a few of the key points backwards or completely wrong. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Ellcrys If your problem is solved with this answer, click the V mark of this answer to close the question. Also Please don't post the same as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

BLUEPIXY's response was more than helpful in solving this. Thanks again.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_ELEMENT_LENGTH 10

struct data {
    int numbers[MAX_ELEMENT_LENGTH];
    int length;
};

void insert(struct data *x, int newNumber){
    int i, k;

    if(x->length == 0){
        x->numbers[x->length++] = newNumber;
    } else if(x->length < MAX_ELEMENT_LENGTH){//need this check
        //x->length = x->length + 1;//Do not increment before the loop. because x->numbers[i] occurs out of bounds

        for(i = 0; i < x->length; i++){   //descending order
            if(x->numbers[i] < newNumber){//descending order
                //insert position is i
                for(k = x->length-1; k >= i; k--){//k > i --> k >= i
                    x->numbers[k+1] = x->numbers[k];
                }
                break;//exit loop
            }
        }
        x->numbers[i] = newNumber;
        x->length++;
    }
}

int main(void){
    //DEMO
    struct data x = { {0}, 0 };

    insert(&x, 5);
    for(int i = 1; i < 11; ++i)
        insert(&x, i);

    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; ++i)
        printf("%d ", x.numbers[i]);
    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```